# Transfer date from filename to metadata "date taken" tag

Tags: windows, exif, metadata

I have several gigabytes of family photos that I want to upload to Google Photos. Unfortunately the time tag for these images are in the filename rather than then in the "date taken" metadata tag.

Is there any way to transfer the date that's in the filename to the "date taken" metadata tag? I am using Windows.

The file names usually go like this:
"1996 0904 (1)" "1996 0904 (2)" = Year MonthDay

Comment: I would also __strongly__ recommend backing up all of your photos __before__ you start.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using **[JHead](http://www.sentex.net/~mwandel/jhead/)** to manipulate JPeg Matadata. It's available for Linux (which I use), but also for OSX and Windows. It's a command-line utility, and can be used e.g. to adjust time stamps of a photo based on its [Exif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_image_file_format) tags – but also to [adjust the Exif tags, if e.g. your camera's time was setup wrongly](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/adjust-exif-time-date-jpeg-photo/start)

For details, it has a documentation (and a man page on Linux). In your case, you would use something like `jhead -ts <yyyy:mm:dd-hh:mm:ss> *.[jJ][pP][gG]`, replacing the part in angle brackets with what you've extracted from the corrsponding file names.